# Using a common object in the portlet and in *LocalServiceImpl

Tags: java, liferay

I'd like to use a common object *MyObject* in the portlet and in *LocalServiceImpl.java.

In the portlet I'm populating *MyObject* with the values of the http request.
Then I'd like to pass this object to a method in *LocalServiceImpl.java.

*MyObject* class is in the same package as the Portlet.

But when I'm building the services *LocalServiceWrapper is complaining that it can't found the package where I put *MyObject*.

Where should I put this class?

I'm using Liferay 6.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your MyObject class under service package that gets generated when you build service.
Then you will not face any error while building services.

Comment: Thanks it works. I thought about that before but I was wondering if it was a good practice as the service package is automatically generated.

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary (or even good practice) to do so. Be careful when you add WEB-INF/service as source folder to your project: You might end up with the same classes twice on the classpath - this can be a source for annoying bugs and long debugging sessions